# syntax error near unexpected token else in shell script

Tags: shell

I have this shell script which takes 2 parameters but when i run this it shows me this error.What do I need to do to write this if-then-else block correctly?

NK_BILLED_UNBILLED_DATA.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
'K_BILLED_UNBILLED_DATA.sh: line 31:`  else

### Shell Script

```
echo Script Name: "$0"
echo Total Number of Argument Passed: "$#"
echo Arguments List -
echo 1. $2
if test -d $2;then

        echo "Welcome $2"

else

        echo "Not Exist";

        fi


echo All Arguments are: "$*"


ORACLE_SID=BSCS01U
export ORACLE_SID

export PATH=.:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

export BC=$1
echo "$BC"

if [ $# -ne 0 ];then

    export REPORT_GEN_PATH=$2;

    else 

    export REPORT_GEN_PATH=$WORK/Reports/ANT001A_REQ01/generated_reports;

fi

export REPORT_HOME=$BSCS_WORKDIR/Reports/ANT001A_REQ01

echo "Please wait....The Billed and Unbilled report is being created."
sqlplus SYSADM/SYSADM@$ORACLE_SID << eof_disp > $REPORT_HOME/logs/log_file_$$.log
        @$REPORT_HOME/scripts/GEN_BILLED_UNBILLED_REPORT_FILE.sql
eof_disp

echo "Billed and Unbilled report created."
```

Comment: Escape your variables. `"$1"` `"$2"` `test -d "$2"` echo "1, $2"` . `export PATH=.:$PATH` is bad, do `export PATH="$(pwd):$PATH"`. You may want to add a tag with the shell you are using (bash?). The script looks ok, how do you call it ?

Comment: sh NK_BILL_UNBILLED_DATA.sh 03 /directory

Comment: Your script works perfectly find on [raxtester](http://rextester.com/DEHMTD37264). There is something missing.